# Resquest time included STW (Garbage Collection) time in Java (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, latency

Are there any request time metric in catalina jmx, that account Garbage Collection time (if apply)?

I know the metrics for GC time but i am searching for something that reflects the request time end to end inside JVM.

Thanks a lot.

JMX metric for request time end to end inside JVM.

Answer (score 1):

In https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html I read:

> "Connections are queued inside the server socket created by the
> Connector until a thread becomes available to process the connection.
> Once maxConnections has been reached the operating system will queue
> further connections. The size of the operating system provided
> connection queue may be controlled by the acceptCount attribute. If
> the operating system queue fills, further connection requests may be
> refused or may time out."

And:

> "acceptCount   The maximum length of the operating system provided
> queue for incoming connection requests when maxConnections has been
> reached. The operating system may ignore this setting and use a
> different size for the queue. When this queue is full, the operating
> system may actively refuse additional connections or those connections
> may time out. The default value is 100."

So the queue pool is "outside" JVM and there isn't any JMX metric for it, therefore request time metric that include stop-the-world time is not posible.

What whe can do is to monitor queue pool from the operating system with next command:

```
ss -lt sport 10432
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q         Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port     Process
LISTEN     0          100                        *:10432                    *:*
```

In above example, Tomcat is listening in port 10432. Have a 100 queue connection pool limit and 0 connections in queue. Recv-Q and Send-Q reflects connections in queue pool and Max connections in queue pool respectively when the command is issue in a Listen state port.

I did Next command:

```
while true ;do
ss -lt sport 10432
done
```

And queue pool increase when full Garbage Collection take place so it's very important to put an eye in Garbage Collection spent time metric.

Thanks.